# See sanitized sql query

Tags: python, psycopg2

The [advised way to run a parameterized query](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#the-problem-with-the-query-parameters) with psycopg2, if I understand correctly, is to use the second argument to the execute method:

```py
SQL = "INSERT INTO authors (name) VALUES (%s);"
data = ("O'Reilly", )
cur.execute(SQL, data)
```

This will sanitize the data, do quoting, etc. That's great. Less great is it appears to be opaque;  it seems to be a black box that modifies my code. I'd like to see what the actual query sent to the database is. Is there some way to see that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [cursor.mogrify](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.mogrify) method to print the query with interpolated values:

```
>>> conn = psycopg2.connect(database='test')
>>> cur = conn.cursor()
>>> cur.mogrify('SELECT foo, bar, baz FROM quux WHERE a = %s', (42,))
b'SELECT foo, bar, baz FROM quux WHERE a = 42'
```

Note that this is a psycopg2-specific method - it won't work for other DB-API connectors.